# android create listView with different cells height and width

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I want to a create list view with multiple raw and each cell has a different height and width, what is the best way to do that? do i use a gridView? or GridLayout? or listView(this is the last choice)[image: Example of my gridView]

Comment: what about TableLayout?

Comment: yes! One of the choices but dont you think it is better!!

Comment: this is my question, what is better to use in this case? i will try it

Answer (score 0):

Todo the things that you asked in an easier way, android introduced RecyclerView. You can create listview, gridview, staggered gridview by just using recyclerview. For more info about Recyclerview refer 
[Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html)

Comment: what do you advice me to use with this class? grid view ?

Comment: RecyclerView.Layoutmanager can have Linearlayoutmanager or gridlayoutmanager. So you can use based on style you want.